# Instantiating a class based on paramters in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have a slightly different problem where I'm instantiating a class from within another class which works when I manually invoke the method but doesn't when I automate it.  The code is below:

```
class Button {
     function __construct($params = Array()) {
         // get some common properties
     }
}

class HelperButton extends Button {
     function __construct($params = Array()) {
         parent::__construct($params);
     }
     function getHelperButton() {
         //generate helper button code
     }
}
```

I'm using the above class in the following classes

```
include_once('field.class.php');
include_once('buttons.class.php');

class Field {
    function __construct() {

    }
    function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class TextField extends Field {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function setFiller($fill = "") {
        $helperbtn = new HelperButton($fill);
        $this->helperbtn = $helperbtn->getHelperButton();
    }
    function getTextField(){
        $this->textfield = "<input name='blah' />".$this->heperbtn;
        return $this->textfield;
    }
}

class Segment extends Field {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function addTextField($params = array()) {
        if(is_array($params)){
            $txtfld = new TextField();
        }
        if (isset($params['type']['filler'])) {
            $txtfld->setFiller($params['type']['fill']);
        }
        $this->segment .= $txtfld->getTextField();
    }
    function addFillerField($params = array()) {
        $params['type']['filler'] = true;
        $this->addTextField($params);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm generating the text field in my page dynamically with params.  The following code works well:

```
$segment = new Segment();
$segment->addFillerField("type"=>array("filler"=>true,"fill"=>"sometext")); //this should add a button next to the field which will open a window that will load the 'fill' text
$segment->render(); // this will print the segment output to screen
```

However, the following code does not work. It prints the text field alright but it does not print the button:

```
$fldmthds = array("FLRFLD" => "FillerField");
$pagedtl = array("FCLSID" => "FLRFLD", "FLDNAM" => "Field Name", "FLDTYP" => "filler:true,fill:sometext");

$mysegment = new Segment();

foreach ($pagedtl as $flds => $val) {
    $mthd = "add" . $fldmthds[$val['FCLSID']];  // resolves to addFillerField
    $params = array(
        'name' => $val['FLDNAM'],
        'type' => json_decode("{" . $val['FLDTYP'] . "}", true)
    );

    $mysegment->{$mthd}($params);
}
$mysegment->render();
```

PHP did not give any error/warning.  It just goes silent and forgets the button.  Does anyone see what is going wrong here?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: `$fldmthds = array("FLRFLD" => "FillerField");` is missing the closing semicolon (;) at the line end, are you aware?

Comment: Thanks Tom. That's a miss when I copy-pasted.

Comment: Thank you.Can you also show the code of your `Field` class?

Comment: Edited to include Field class now

Comment: `$pagedtl` is an array of strings, so inside your `foreach` loop, `$val['FCLSID']` should trigger a warning because `$val` will be a string, not an array. If it doesn't I would check for runtime changes to `display_errors` or `error_reporting`

Comment: `$pagedtl` is a db output (key-value pair), I have given just the significant fields for simplicity (typed it here instead of copy-paste, may be I should have used single quotes for the keys. sorry about that).  It works alright in parsing and printing the text field, it just doesn't print the helper button beneath it.

Comment: `$mysegment->{$mthd}($params);` ends up calling non-existing function "add"

Comment: It exists in the `Segment` class (as given here).  I tracked the issue from the other answer.  Thanks for your time Tom.

Comment: My pleasure.Lastly, The below should be filler,not fill: `$txtfld->setFiller($params['type']['filler']);`

Comment: It will be `fill` and not `filler`. That's actually the second parameter I'm passing as in `$segment->addFillerField("type"=>array("filler"=>true,"fill"=>"sometext"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't comment for now... just one thing: json_decode() will fail. To receive valid json change `{filler:true,fill:sometext}` to `{"filler": true, "fill": "sometext"}`

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was the issue.